# getting records in list in select doesn't constrain to list in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table:

1. Is a list of company info
2. A list of company names that are duplicates of table 1

I have trying to get all of the duplicate records in Table 1 by using `IN`

```
SELECT *
from company
where name in
        (
        SELECT name from `temp_duplicate_company`
        )
```

The problem is this returns all the records in Table 1 company table and not just those in the duplicates table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Select * from company a
inner join temp_duplicate_company b on a.name = b.name
```

This would only give you the names that can be joined to `temp_duplicate_company`

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.*, count(a.name) counts
from company a
left join temp_duplicate_company b using (name)
group by a.name;
```

This should show you the number of times the names repeat as well.